# Python - JIT compiler for C++

Tags: python, c++, jit

Currently I am using distutils for building and ctypes for interfacing, but I bump into this, which seems very nice

```
import ROOT 

cppFunctionCode = '''
void f() {
std::cout << "Hi jitted C. world!" « std::endl; 
}'''

ROOT.gInterpreter.Declare(cppFunctionCode) 
ROOT.f() # Hello!
```

https://root.cern.ch/code-snippet/interpreted-cpp-python

The problem is that ROOT is a very big framework, and it would be nice to have a tool that does only the C++ JIT and not the rest.

Does anybody know if there is a simple library for C++ JIT from python like this?

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but there are numerous JIT compilers for Python code which execute at C++ speeds, such as HOPE and Numba:

https://github.com/cosmo-ethz/hope
https://github.com/numba/numba

There is also Pythran, which exports code to compiled C++ code:
https://github.com/serge-sans-paille/pythran

And less optimized but more portable is Nuitka:
http://nuitka.net/

However, all compile pure Python code to C++.

If you want the other way, you could try exporting classes via Boost::Python.

Comment: Thanks. I can't remember well if this could be done with BoostPython. I mean without a interface file.

Comment: It can be, but you have to export the classes to Python from C++, meaning you have to write C++ modules, compile them, and then export them (and not on the fly, like this).

The good news is this avoids "one more module". The bad news is, no JIT compiler.

However, if C++ isn't your end goal, and you'd rather write pure-python code optimized as C++, Numba especially is amazing.

Here's a wonderful blog on how you can get C++ speeds using a JIT without actually writing C++:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Python_Is_Not_C_Take_Two?lang=en

Comment: But as far as the core question, and why I'm commenting: I don't have a direct answer, I don't know of any C++ JIT compiler for Python other than PyRoot, unfortunately. But I do know many, potentially suitable alternatives. (I personally use Numba for all my code).

Comment: I will definitely give Numba a try in the future, it looks very powerfull, but for this project I need some C++ libraries and is pretty specific. I have my one dirty code that takes a C++ string and builds it with distutils and loads the binary with ctypes, nevertheless it has a lot of hardcoded stuff but it works.

Comment: If you would like to look at exporting those classes to Python using Boost, here's a quick tutorial (I used to use this prior to Numba). This should suit your needs, but it's not a JIT. But if you just need to export pre-existing libraries to be wrapped in Python, Boost can work (and is probably the best solution).

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html